# Setting Gmaps bounds in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps

I want to display a whole country, but it zooms in to a street level somewhere in the middle of the country.

I am looking for a way to set the bounds to display the full country/region requested. I know there are bound coordinates but is there a property or a call I can make in pandas/python that will set it for the figure?

Everything I have found on Google so far was related C# and not python/pandas.

```
#get the coordinates for google maps API
gmaps.configure(api_key=cfg.key)

#build request
params = {'key': cfg.key}
params['address'] = f"{targetLocation}"

response = requests.get(cfg.baseApiUrl, params=params)

#convert response to json
response = response.json()

northeastLatBounds = response["results"][0]["geometry"]["bounds"]["northeast"]["lat"]
northeastLngBounds = response["results"][0]["geometry"]["bounds"]["northeast"]["lng"]
southwestLatBounds = response["results"][0]["geometry"]["bounds"]["southwest"]["lat"]
southwestLngBounds = response["results"][0]["geometry"]["bounds"]["southwest"]["lng"]

coordinates = pd.DataFrame({'lat': response["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],
                            'lng': response["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]}, index=[0])
coordinates.loc[1] = [northeastLatBounds] + [northeastLngBounds]
coordinates.loc[2] = [southwestLatBounds] + [southwestLngBounds]
coordinates
```

Please note the coordinates Dataframe was for my marker layer. I thought that entering the bounds there would help, but now I have 3 markers and doesn't look clean. Any help would be great!

Comment: I would be better if you give a full example: what's in you cfg file?

Comment: @godot not really sure what that has to do with anything considering it's not even related lol I can pull data just fine and this isn't an issue about that :) I just not sure how I can set the bounds of my country. IE I put in Italy but it zooms in to a street on rome, not showing the country as a whole. Config file has  config things like API key and base URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't find any property settings like we have in C# so I created a "hard coding" of the zoom level based on whether it was a country or region being searched for. Not exactly what I wanted to do but it gets the job done.